# Read contents of directory, output results randomly with HTML tag title php (working but not title)

Tags: php, html, dom, random, tags

So far my script is working fine,  basically it gets all htm files, out puts results, however im using DOM to get the HTML title tag from each file, that's where im not get to get it in the random array..  (image basenames and htm basename files are the same (firstresult.htm has picture firstresult.jpg)

I hope the code I provide and answer will be useful

```
<?php
// loop through the images
$count = 0;
$filenamenoext = array();

foreach (glob("/mydirectory/*.htm") as $filename) {
$filenamenoext[$count] = basename($filename, ".htm");


$count++;
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
$random = mt_rand(1, $count - 1);


$cachefile = "$filename";
$contents = file($cachefile); 
$string = implode($contents);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($string);
$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
//get and display what you need:
$title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


 echo '<a href="'.$filenamenoext[$random].'.htm"><img class="image" src="'.$filenamenoext[$random].'.jpg" " />"'.$title.'"</A><BR><BR>';

 }

?>
```

Comment: Does it show any errors? Maybe it isn't creating a `DOMDocument`. Remove the `@` from the line `@$doc->loadHTML($string);` and run again, edit your post if you see an error message.

Comment: thanks, it doesnt show errors just something to do with the />"'.$title.'"</  part i think.. ..  beacuse without the random code everything loads properly.

Comment: Is this your full php code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `$filename` variable you use on the line `$cachefile = "$filename";` hasn't been set. It's only defined **in** the *foreach loop's scope.*

You should change it to

```
$cachefile = $filenamenoext[$random] . '.htm';
```

---

Also, it's a better practice to use [array_push()](http://php.net/array_push) and [count()](http://php.net/count) functions, instead of using a counter and manually filling the array. At least the code is *better looking* and *more readable*.

```
<?php
// loop through the images
$count         = 0;
$filenamenoext = array();

foreach (glob("/mydirectory/*.htm") as $filename) {
    array_push($filenamenoext, basename($filename, ".htm"));
}
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $random = mt_rand(1, count($filenamenoext) - 1);


    $cachefile = $filenamenoext[$random] . '.htm';
    $contents  = file($cachefile);
    $string    = implode($contents);
    $doc       = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($string);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    //get and display what you need:
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


    echo '<a href="' . $filenamenoext[$random] . '.htm"><img class="image" src="' . $filenamenoext[$random] . '.jpg" " />"' . $title . '"</A><BR><BR>';

}

?>
```

Comment: thank you worked perfecly although i had to change   $cachefile to since at topped we stripped the ext.   $cachefile = "$filenamenoext[$random].htm";

Comment: i've edited the answer, please vote up and/or accept it if it helped. thank you!